# Will I get shot if I delete a question and repost?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I am specifically asking about this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35858/what-other-question-answer-knowledgebase-web-applications-are-around, which started life on serverfault.

Clearly, I did not word my question clearly, and it was pounced on and moved here. I want to clean up and post a clarified question, I would prefer on serverfault, but based on [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) comment I would post on Superuser, where I believe I will be more likely to get better feedback than here, in part because the question is not meta.

So, if I delete, and repost a clarified question, will I raise the ire of the community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently, this is how you do it...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638/which-cms-or-other-framework-should-i-use-to-develop-a-stackoverflow-like-site)

(So yeah, chances are if you post it again it'll get closed as a duplicate...)

Comment: Sounds like Montell Jordan. Or at the least, Acafellas.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure your question is appropriate for any site we have, honestly.

On Super User, it's a website question, which isn't really allowed -- it's just a "list of websites". Doesn't deal with computer software or hardware at all.

Comment: Here is my attempt to formulate the new question:
What web-based CMS/knowledge-base applications can be used to build a Question/Answer style knowledgebase

Comment: still not relevant; I would vote to close it across every site we run. The fundamental weakness is that it's a "LETS MAKE A LIST OF X!!" type of question.

Comment: @EricJLN - the answer is, "Every CMS can be used to make a question/answer site!"  The question itself is far, far, far too broad.

Answer (score 1):

No

The fact that it is on another site, and that you are completely removing the old question means that you are less likely to get a angry commentor.

Even if you do, it is one person. It isn't like the entire site will rain down on you with mass downvotes and obliterate all hope of you ever posting again. That only happens when someone accused Jon Skeet of being wrong.

BTW, you can delete a question, edit it, and then undelete it if you want to take it out of commission for a few minutes. (Or at least you can do this with answers). This would have the benefit of not creating a new Question ID, and not requiring you to recreate the entire question.

I have not actually looked into your question and whether it is appropriate for the sites. See Jeff's Answer for that.